# How to configure JCache within Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to "spring boot" (so bear with me) and am having a few issues configuring the caching to use JSR107.

I've put "spring boot" in quotes as I don't believe I'm actually doing this in a spring boot way.

I'm using WebApplicationInitializer to bring up the application when deployed as a war to tomcat.

```py
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context)
    {
        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webApplicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        webApplicationContext.register(CacheConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = context.addServlet("dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

That class registers AppConfig & CacheConfig, which are as follows:

```py
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:configurable-application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    ... a few bean definitions here, not relevant to this issue
}
```

```py
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig
{
    public CacheConfig()
    {
        CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        System.out.println("STARTUP: CachingProvider " + provider.getClass());

        CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();
        System.out.println("STARTUP: CacheManager " + cacheManager.getClass());

        System.out.println("STARTUP: CacheManager URI " + cacheManager.getURI());

        Iterable<String> caches = cacheManager.getCacheNames();

        for (String cacheName : caches)
        {
            System.out.println("STARTUP: CACHE " + cacheName);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have some debug in there, and indeed it looks to be creating the correct CacheManager and Provider, but no caches exist.

```
STARTUP: CachingProvider class org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
STARTUP: CacheManager class org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager
STARTUP: CacheManager URI urn:X-ehcache:jsr107-default-config
```

I assume it's doing this from looking at the jars available on the classpath.

I have the following in application.properties

```
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
```

And indeed that ehcache.xml exists on the classpath, but I don't think it's ever being read as I'm getting no debug from the cache name loop debug shown above.

I've tried sticking the @EnableCaching tag on the CacheConfig class, but then I get the following error

```
No CacheResolver specified, and no bean of type CacheManager found.
```

Yet, the debug is exactly the same as above, indicating I have a CachingProvider and a CacheManager.

Any help would be appreciated. Trying to avoid using the magic of spring boot, and would like to be more explicit about the configuration, as you can probably tell.